# Pesquisa maiores vendedores SQL

Tags: sql-server

Preciso de um código SQL que me mostre os melhores vendedores mas no resultado me mostre de qual das lojas esse funcionario pertence.

Consigo fazer a pesquisa de saber quais são os melhores vendedores mas não sei selecionar de qual loja ele é. Segue abaixo o meu código:

```
select distinct co_operador, count(*) as qtidade_lib
from [dbo].[pistb002_liberacao_beneficio]
group by co_operador
order by "qtidade_lib" desc
```

Comment: E onde está gravada a loja? Outra tabela? Na mesma?

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que exista uma tabela de lojas chamada TbLojas e ela esteja relacionada ao a esta tabela que usou no exemplo atravez do campo LojaID.

A Instrução ficaria +- assim:

```
select distinct B.co_operador, L.NomeLoja, count(B.*) as qtidade_lib
from [dbo].[pistb002_liberacao_beneficio] B
Inner Join TbLojas L
ON B.LojaID = L.LojaID
group by B.co_operador, L.NomeLoja
order by "qtidade_lib" desc
```

Se puder dar mais informação sobre onde está a tabela de lojas e como ela é relacionada a esta tabela de beneficio fica mais fácil...